# How can I make my application have a 30 day trial period

Tags: c#, winforms, licensing, trial

how to create trial period setup file for 30 days of my c# windows application?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20676008/1207195

Answer (score 8):

Making C# application a 30 day trial version

http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/130150-Making-C-application-day-trial-version.aspx

How to add more functionality in setup file? - C#

http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread226490.html

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution is to use the registry and write there in some key the installation date. This step is done in the installation time/ first time the application is in use. Then periodically check the current date against the installation date.

You can take also these references:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Trial_Maker.aspx
2. http://trial.qarchive.org/
3. [Using .Net built-in classes](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/Forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=66480)

Comment: Please give me stepwise solution.